# How to test @Input() item: any in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a Angular project, and want to test some components.

So I want to test the @Input()item: any. Because this is the component:

```
export class EcheqViewItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() item: any;

  constructor() {}
```

And the template looks like this:

```
<div class="echeq-view-item">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
       <mat-icon
        *ngIf="item.status === 'Submitted'"
        color="primary"
        mat-card-avatar
      >
        done_outline
      </mat-icon> -->
      <mat-icon *ngIf="item.status === 'Active'" color="warn" mat-card-avatar>
        highlight_off
      </mat-icon>
      <mat-card-title>{{ item.title }}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>{{
        item.assignedOnUtc | date: 'dd MMM'
      }}</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content> </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-footer class="echeq-view-item-footer">
      {{ item.progress }} %
    </mat-card-footer>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

And I have the test like this:

```
describe('EcheqViewItemComponent', () => {
  let component: EcheqViewItemComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EcheqViewItemComponent>;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({

      imports:[ParticipantEcheqModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EcheqViewItemComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;


    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But at the moment if I run the test I get this error:

```
EcheqViewItemComponent should create
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///ParticipantEcheqModule/EcheqViewItemComponent.ngfactory.js:62:31)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20432:1)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:19828:1)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20069:1)
    at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20011:1)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:19834:1)
    at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20722:1)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20400:1)
    at ViewRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:18209:1)
    at ComponentFixture.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/testing.js.ComponentFixture._tick (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/testing.js:227:1)
```

So my question is, how to fix this?

Thank you

if I do it like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    component.item = {
      status: true
  }
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EcheqViewItemComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;


    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

still get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'item' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to arrange the `item` object in the `beforeEach` block:

```
beforeEach(() => {
   component.item = {
       status: true
   }
}
```

This is happening when your component is injected to the `TestBed` module it does not have the value in the item object.

Another way of doing this would be mocking the parent component and setting the value for the `item` before binding it.

Comment: please do it after you have created the component instance

Answer (score 0):

you can use the $any type cast function to silence the error :

```
<div class="echeq-view-item">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
       <mat-icon
        *ngIf="$any(item).status === 'Submitted'"
        color="primary"
        mat-card-avatar
      >
        done_outline
      </mat-icon> -->
      <mat-icon *ngIf="$any(item).status === 'Active'" color="warn" mat-card-avatar>
        highlight_off
      </mat-icon>
      <mat-card-title>{{ $any(item).title }}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>{{
        item.assignedOnUtc | date: 'dd MMM'
      }}</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content> </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-footer class="echeq-view-item-footer">
      {{ item.progress }} %
    </mat-card-footer>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answare, but then I get this error: Unknown method '$any'Angular

Comment: It's mentioned in the official documentation https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-any-type-cast-function